# Seaborn lmplot - Changing Marker Style and Color of single Datapoint

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I was trying to find an answer to Harvards CS109, Homework 1, Part 1c from the year 2013 using seaborn, which they don't.

*"Choose a plot to show this relationship and specifically annotate the Oakland baseball team on the on the plot. Show this plot across multiple years. In which years can you detect a competitive advantage from the Oakland baseball team of using data science? When did this end?"*

So we do have for multiple years and multiple teams, salaries as well as wins. I want to build a seaborn facet for each year regressing salaries against wins AND call out the datapoint for Oakland. Building the facet for one regression for each year works fine. But how would I change the data point for oakland?

Thats how my data looks like (the first 5 entries):

```
teamID yearID   salary      W
0   ANA 1997    31135472    84
1   ANA 1998    41281000    85
2   ANA 1999    55388166    70
3   ANA 2000    51464167    82
4   ANA 2001    47535167    75
...
```

This is how I am plotting the data:

> facetplots = sns.lmplot(x="salary", y="W", col="yearID", data=df_data,     col_wrap=4, size=3)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Overplot with only the single point you want to highlight.

Comment: could you elaborate on that? Or point towards relevant documentation? I am fairly new to the whole pandas/matplotlib/seaborn stuff. And maybe formulate it as a full answer, so that I can accept it as the answer.